# Regex stl not working

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm trying to verify if a string correspons to a regex with the stl like this :

```
regex rgx("#^\([ \r\t\n\f]*([-]?[0-9]+)[ \r\t\n\f]*,[ \r\t\n\f]*([-]?[0-9]+)[ \r\t\n\f]*\)$#");
bool test = regex_search("(12,3)", rgx);
```

The string is supposed to match, but test = false after that !

Comment: Which compiler? And this is definitely not part of the STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your literal to Raw literal:

```
regex rgx(R"#(^\([ \r\t\n\f]*([-]?[0-9]+)[ \r\t\n\f]*,[ \r\t\n\f]*([-]?[0-9]+)[ \r\t\n\f]*\)$)#");
```

BTW, I believe the following regexp is identical to yours but much simpler:

```
regex rgx(R"#(^\(\s*(-?\d+)\s*,\s*(-?\d+)\s*\)$)#");
```

Or without raw literals:

```
regex rgx("^\\(\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*\\)$")
```

Comment: Or, if the compiler doesn't support raw literals, change each backslash into two backslashes.

Comment: Now i have
    regex rgx("#(^\\(\\s*([-]?\\d+)\\s*,\\s*([-]?\\d+)\\s*\\)$)#");
But still not working

Comment: @user2898190 - the new regex still has a lone backslash. But before you continue this possibly futile effort, if you're using gcc you're doomed. The regex support there is just worthless stubs.

Comment: if you don't have raw literals you should remove hashes(#) from the start and the end, so it should look like this: `regex rgx("^\\(\\s*([-]?\\d+)\\s*,\\s*([-]?\\d+)\\s*\\)$")`

Comment: @PeteBecker for what is worth, the recently released version of libstdc++ has `<regex>` now.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - has that been released? I though it was still in testing...